# get data from all input Except one text box

Tags: jquery

```
$('input:text').each(function (n, element) 
   {
      if ($(element).val() != '')
      {

      }
});
```

this code to get value from all text box in page , but how i can use this code to get all input data Except one text box

Comment: how can you uniquely identify each input element? By id, class, etc? You will need some logic to exclude the one you want.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Jeff's answer, you can also use .not() to remove the item from your original set:

```
$('input:text').not(selector).each(function (n, element)
```

You will still need some way to indentify the textbox you wish to exclude. This way is a little more robust as you can use a selector, the actual element(s) or a function as the selector argument for .not().

As well, the resulting code can be a little easier to read rather than trying to decypher multiple nested filters/selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Change the selector so that it doesn't select the textbox you don't want. If the textbox has an id of `ignoreMe` then the new selector would be:

```
$('input:text:not(input#ignoreMe)')
```